# makefile give error undefined reference to 'main'

Tags: c, makefile

Makefile:

```
all: a.out

a.out: b.o a.o 
    gcc -o b.o a.o

a.o: a.c 
    gcc -c a.c

b.o: b.c 
    gcc -c b.c

.PHONY:clean

clean:
    rm *.o a.out
```

with `make`, give information:

> error: undefined reference to 'main'
>
> collect2: ld return 1
>
> make: *** [a.out] error 1

But when put source file `a.c` and `b.c` into Eclipse CDT, it compiles well.
Please explain what is wrong with my `makefile`?

PS:
a.c:

```
int global_1 = 100;
```

b.c:

```
extern int global_1;

int main()
{
    int global_2 = global_1 * 2;
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This rule doesn't specify the correct result file:

```
a.out: b.o a.o 
    gcc -o b.o a.o
```

It should be

```
a.out: b.o a.o 
    gcc -o "$@" b.o a.o
```

That's what you get for violating one of [Paul's Rules of Makefiles](http://mad-scientist.net/make/rules.html). BTW, it's not the makefile that "gives the error", it's the compilation, specifically the linker.

Answer (score 0):

This:

```
a.out: b.o a.o 
    gcc -o b.o a.o
        \----/
           |
           |
     this says "name
     the output b.o"
```

is overwriting the `b.o` object file with the output file. I'm pretty sure `make` is clever enough to figure the required command out without any input, so try deleting the second line.

Comment: Sorry, when deleting the second line as you said, the `make` command would not generate `a.out` executable. I'm using ubuntu 12.04 default make.